# Computing $P(X)$ given $P(Y)$ and $P(Y | X)$

Tags: probability

I have two binary variables $X$ and $Y$.

$P(Y = 0 | X = 0) = 1.0$

$P(Y = 1 | X = 0) = 0.0$

$P(Y = 0 | X = 1) = 0.5$

$P(Y = 1 | X = 1) = 0.5$

And I am given $P(Y = 1) = 0.9$.

How do I compute $P(X = 1)$? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is contain contradictory information.

Comment: Thanks. Happy to close it, but I can't see a button for doing this.

Comment: That's OK. I believe you can edit/erase your Question. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the data is correct. Using the law of total probability,

$\begin{align}
P(Y=1)&=P(Y=1|X=0)P(X=0)+P(Y=1|X=1)P(X=1)\\
{\therefore\space}0.9&=(0.5)P(X=1)\\
{\implies}P(X=1)&>1
\end{align}$

This contradicts that fact that $0\le{P(X={x})}\le{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).
\begin{align}P(Y=1) &= P(Y=1, X=0) + P(Y=1,X=1)\\
&= P(Y=1 \mid X=0) \cdot P(X=0) + P(Y=1 \mid X=1) \cdot P(X=1).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Substituting from the input gives me that P(X = 1) = 1.8 though, so I must be doing something wrong? (The first term in the sum vanishes because P(Y = 1 | X = 0) is 0. The second part is 0.5 P(X = 1).

Comment: @user2771184 Yes, so there is some typo in the question.

Comment: Well, how can you combine a $0.5$ probability and a $0$ probability to get a $0.9$ probability? You can't. The problem is flawed, not your calculation.

Comment: Thank you! You are right! I must have missed something.